# How to sequentially extract video segments from mp4/mkv video files?

Tags: ruby, ffmpeg, jruby, mp4, mkv

Is there a way to programmatically walk through a file and extract (for example) consecutive 10-second fragments from it into separate files?

A colleague is currently using `ffmpeg` for this, but I'm thinking that invoking this command once per segment will result in a *lot* of file seeking that may not be necessary.

Or am I wrong, is there some kind of time index in these files that makes the seeks very fast?

The language currently used for calling ffmpeg is Ruby, so a compiled C library might work, and a Java library would definitely work (with JRuby).

Comment: Video processing and hardcore computation is not Ruby's forte, but as you stated, you could find bindings for ffmpeg, VLC, or any other video library that fits the type of file you need to process. Your question seems to be asking for a library, but at the same time state what you are already using with Ruby, so little unclear to me.

Comment: He is currently making system calls and running the ffmpeg executable.

Comment: This is what the [segment muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment) does.

Comment: Really, the system calls are going to be insignificant compared to what ffmpeg is doing and the disk access, and unless this is some process that is running constantly and is time-sensitive, the additional file seeks that ffmpeg needs to do aren't going to make much difference of anything. It would likely be an improvement to keep the stream open on ffmpeg's side of things, but that kust means configuring what commands you give.

Comment: @Gyan There it is, I assumed there was a command, but my ffmpeg experience was amounts to some dabbling years ago, lol.